# What is the name/title of someone that merges things?

Tags: single-word-requests

If I was a thing/person who merges things, what would my title be? Merger is the end product, and there doesn't seem to be something similar to "comparator".

I'm actually looking to name a software tool which merges two objects.

Comment: Interesting, try ***consolidator***, or ***integrator***.

Comment: A *merger* isn't actually the end product - it is the whole process. But I agree that its existence would seem to preclude its use for *one who merges*.

Answer (score 2):

Software is often named for what it does or what it helps to create. *Spreadsheet software* is not a spread sheet in itself; it helps make spreadsheets. What helps you edit videos? *Video editing software*!

I would just call it [merger software](https://www.google.com/#q=%22merger+software%22), or similar (merge, merging).

There are some variations of this that may also work:

- [Joiner software](https://www.google.com/#q=%22joiner+software%22)

  - "25 Best Free File Joiner Software"
- [Combining software](https://www.google.com/#q=%22combining+software%22)

  - "PDF Combining Software"

---

When you try to describe people the same way, it comes off very informal, and sometimes it's not something anyone says. It can also come off as rude. *You're our coffee guy* means that you're the person (usually an intern) that gets our coffee.

(I would not use any of the above suggestions to describe a person.)

Answer (score 1):

**Integrator** — [Dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/integrator)

> *noun* 1. a person or thing that integrates.

Comment: I liked this at first glance and then remembered mathematical software that integrates.

Answer (score 0):

The software can be called *Merge*.

The description of the software would say: this software merges two __________.

Example: PDF SAM -- Split and Merge.

Which is similar to the software called "Cloud Convert".